# how to change docker image source in Openstack kolla?

Tags: docker, ansible, openstack

hi i am trying to install `cloud-kitty` service using open stack kolla-ansible , during the installation when it try to pull container / images from dockerhub it throw error `The container image not found cloudkitty-api:ussuri` , when i check on docker hub the required image not present there but there are
same images present with this name `objectiflibre/cloudkitty-api` .what/how should i change in kolla-ansible so that it `pull` specify image for `cloudkitty`.

I try to change the cloudkitty default/main.yml but i dont understand how should i change or what should i change in this.

`/root/kolla-openstack/share/kolla-ansible/ansible/roles/cloudkitty/defaults/main.yml`

```
####################
# Docker
####################
cloudkitty_install_type: "{{ kolla_install_type }}"
cloudkitty_tag: "{{ openstack_tag }}"

cloudkitty_api_image: "{{ docker_registry ~ '/' if docker_registry else '' }}{{ docker_namespace }}/{{ kolla_base_distro }}-{{ cloudkitty_install_type }}-cloudkitty-api"
cloudkitty_api_tag: "{{ cloudkitty_tag }}"
cloudkitty_api_image_full: "{{ cloudkitty_api_image }}:{{ cloudkitty_api_tag }}"
```

my `globals.yml`

```
###############
# Kolla options
###############
# Valid options are [ COPY_ONCE, COPY_ALWAYS ]
config_strategy: "COPY_ALWAYS"

# Valid options are ['centos', 'debian', 'rhel', 'ubuntu']
kolla_base_distro: "ubuntu"

# Valid options are [ binary, source ]
kolla_install_type: "binary"

# Do not override this unless you know what you are doing.
openstack_release: "ussuri"

# Docker image tag used by default.
#openstack_tag: "{{ openstack_release ~ openstack_tag_suffix }}"

enable_cloudkitty: "yes"
enable_horizon_cloudkitty: "{{ enable_cloudkitty | bool }}"
cloudkitty_collector_backend: "gnocchi"
cloudkitty_storage_backend: "influxdb"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try first to pull the image to my local repo first:

```
#docker pull objectiflibre/cloudkitty-api
```

then  try to  set the correct variables in :

```
/root/kolla-openstack/share/kolla-ansible/ansible/group_vars/all.yml
```

- docker_registry
- docker_namespace
- kolla_base_distro
- cloudkitty_install_type